# xslt select parent of specific nested child

Tags: xml, xslt

i'm not much experienced in Xml/Xslt so hoping the forum would forgive my ignorance. I have the following xml structure, i'm trying to get label "Category 1" no matter where my variable exists in the child/grandchild nodes:
Could you please advise.

=====XML ============

```
<Result>
 <sitemap>
    <node>
        <label>this is top node</label>
        <node>
            <label key="">Category 1</label>
            <node>
                <link>
                   <value>link1</value>
                </link>
            </node>
            <node>
                <link>
                   <value>link2</value>
                </link>
                <node>
                    <link>
                        <value>link21</value>
                    </link>
                </node>
                <node>
                    <link>
                        <value>link22</value>
                    </link>
                </node>
            </node>     
        </node> 

        <node>
            <label key="">Category 2</label>        
        </node>
    </node>
 </sitemap>
</Result>

=================XSLT 2.0 ================ 
<xsl:variable name="myvalue" select="'link22'" />
<xsl:if test="//node[node[link/value=$myvalue]]/node">
   <xsl:value-of select="//node[node[link/value=$myvalue]]/label" />
</xsl:if>
```

=================Output===============
link2

Comment: What is the thing that is going to help you to know to get "Category 1"?  The value of the text being "Category 1"?  Why do you select "link22"  The text of your question does not mention "link22".  Also you say "no matter where my variable exists" ... but what is "your variable"?

Comment: Appreciate your questions, apologies for not making sense there. In my xslt, i have a variable, in this case i have hardcoded to make it simple which is "link22". So I would need "//sitemap/node/node/label" but this would give me Category 1 no matter what as its just a straight reference. What if my varible value is in the Category 2 or anywhere else in the document ? I need to fetch the parent category 1 or category 2 depending on where my variable matches in the child elements. Hope that makes sense but please let me know if further clarification is required. Thanks.

Comment: It's still not clear. If you're "*trying to get label "Category 1"*", then why is "link2" the expected output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am mostly guessing here, but given:

```
<xsl:variable name="myvalue" select="'link22'" />
```

the following instruction:

```
<xsl:value-of select="//link[value=$myvalue]/ancestor::node[label][1]/label" />
```

will return:

```
Category 1
```

---

A more efficient method would use a key to locate the `link` element by its `value`, i.e.:

```
<xsl:key name="link-by-value" match="link" use="value" />
```

(at the top level), and then:

```
<xsl:value-of select="key('link-by-value', $myvalue)/ancestor::node[label][1]/label" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This

```
    <xsl:variable name="myvalue" select="'link22'" />
    <xsl:if test="//node[node/link/value=$myvalue]">
        <xsl:value-of select="//node[node/link/value=$myvalue]/link/value" />
    </xsl:if>
```

Comment: Unfortunately that didn't work but thanks for making me realize the missing xml <link> tags. Updated the above xml. Appreciate your help. Thanks.